# Trouble in jupyter notebook running by line (f10) with VS Code

Tags: python, jupyter, visual-studio-code

Problem:

When I try running code by line (f10) with VS Code, "ipykernel setup required for this feature" message pops up.

What I've tried:

1. Using Anaconda Prompt: "conda install ipykernel", "conda install -c conda-forge ipykernel"

-When I tried this, the prompt said "conda-forge:: ipykernel-6.4.1-py38h595 --> pkgs/main:: ipykernel-6.2.0-py38haa95532_1"

- Doesn't it mean I already install ipykernel v.6.20 or higher?
- After I tried this I checked Jupyter --Version it said ipykernel 5.3.2
- Other specs are qualified. (VS Code, Jupyter, Anaconda versions etc,)

2. Using Terminal (in VS Code): "pip install ipykernel"
3. Reinstalling all of add-ins such as Python for VS, Python, Anaconda, Jupyterlab, VS Code
4. Updating ExecutionPolicy: CurrentUser-RemoteSigned, LocalMachins-AllSigned, others Undefined.

+) Created virtual-env named envi which is conda env. In VS Code I selected this interpreter and also reloaded all windows.

- As I understand, Conda install Ipkkernel > Reload is what pop-up msg required.

This is what I'm going through now.. I just got interested in Python and now I cannot doing anything..

Comment: What's the means of you can not do anything?  You can't run the python file or run the codes in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: I meant I cannot come up with any possible solutions for this. I can run the codes in the Jupyter notebooks w/ VS Code, but still I cannot run the code by line 'cause of "Ipykernel" issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems there was a problem with the version of ipython or ipykernel since I managed to fix it by running the following commands in conda environment:

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

Don't know which of the two was the problem but I was able to use the jupyter notebook line-by-line feature after this.